# How I can catch exception inside context manager?

Tags: python, error-handling, contextmanager

I have case, where I need catch some exception (*in code, for example I want to catch* `ZeroDivisionError`) and handle it inside my own context manager. I need check count of this exception and make print in console. Now, when I run my code, I have catch `ZeroDivisionError` one time and than I have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/example.py", line 23, in foo
    a / b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

For example:

```
class ExceptionCather:
    def __init__(
            self,
            try_counter,
            exc_type=None
    ):
        self.try_counter = try_counter

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        if exc_type == ZeroDivisionError:
            self.try_counter += 1
            if self.try_counter == 2:
                print(self.try_counter)


def foo(a, b):
    try_counter = 0
    while True:
        with ExceptionCather(try_counter):
            a / b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(1, 0)
```

How I can catch error, make print in console and continue with my script? Will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but If you want to handle `ZeroDivisionError` just return `True` from `__exit__`:

```
class ExceptionCather:
    def __init__(
            self,
            try_counter,
            exc_type=None
    ):
        self.try_counter = try_counter

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        if exc_type == ZeroDivisionError:
            self.try_counter += 1
            if self.try_counter == 2:
                print(self.try_counter)
            return True  # This will not raise `ZeroDivisonError`


def foo(a, b):
    try_counter = 0
    while True:
        with ExceptionCather(try_counter):
            a / b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(1, 0)
```

Note also, because you are in while loop, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop loop, `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised which raises `ZeroDivisonError` from your `ExceptionCatcher`(since `__exit__` didn't return `True` at the end).